# C++0x unique_ptr misunderstanding?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

In [N2812](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2812.html) is an example in the *Introduction* where a `unique_ptr` is given as a **value parameter**

```
void push_back2(
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>& l, std::unique_ptr<int> a)
{
  l.push_back(a); // oops: moves from the lvalue 'a', silently!
  l.push_back(a); // oops: 'a' no longer has its original value
}
```

The paper discusses a problem with RValue/LValue overload resolution, but thats not my point.

I wonder, if providing the argument `std::unique_ptr<int> a` **by-value** is not causing a compiler error? **It would copy it**, right? And that is **not allowed** for `unique_ptr`

I am aware that the paper is quite old, maybe the definition of `unique_ptr` has changed, since. But maybe it's just a typo and the author wanted to write `std::unique_ptr<int> &a` instead?

My gcc 4.7.0 agrees with me, but thats no proof :-)

```
void push_back2( std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>&, std::unique_ptr<int> ) { };
int main() {
  list<unique_ptr<int>> lst;
  unique_ptr<int> num { new int{4} };
  push_back2(lst, num); //ERR: use of deleted function
}
```

Comment: You don't need `a` to be a reference, you just need to say `push_back(std::move(a))` and call the function with `move` as well, a la `push_back2(myListPtr, std::move(x));`. The `unique_ptr` forces you to be explicit about moving things around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your knowledge and assumptions about the behavior are correct.

The paper's example is confusing as it is conflating two languages:  C++ with concepts and C++ without concepts.  In the paper's pretend language, the `list` push_back which requires `CopyConstructible` is SFINAE'd away, leaving only the overload requiring `MoveConstructible`.  In such a `list` design, *and* with the old rules that an lvalue could bind to an rvalue-reference, then the `push_back` would have implicitly moved from `a` twice.

Note that we were in no danger at any time of `list` actually behaving this way.  The authors were simply trying to set up a situation where `const value_type&` and `value_type&&` were not overloaded, and you had only `value_type&&` in the overload set.

Comment: Ok. So, there is no "typo" in the paper, the *by-value* is required to get away with one overload possibility. I see.

Comment: It is the `requires CopyConstructible` on the `push_back` that is causing the problem.  In concepts (as it existed just prior to this paper) this is equivalent to what we would do today with `enable_if<is_copy_constructible<value_type>,...>`.  This would leave *only* `push_back(unique_ptr<T>&&)` in the overload set.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with taking the parameter by value.  You are correct that if you try to initialize the parameter by using a copy, you will get a compiler error since that function is deleted.  However, you could initialize the value parameter by providing an rvalue as the argument.  For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> myPtr{ /* ... */ }
std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> elems;
push_back2(elems, myPtr);            // Error, as you've noted
push_back2(elems, std::move(myPtr)); // Fine, uses move constructor to initialize
```

This syntax is nice in that it forces you to explicitly indicate that you're handing the pointer over to the function.

Once you're inside `push_back2`, you are correct that `push_back` won't be able to take in the `unique_ptr` because it will try to use the nonexistent copy constructor.  To fix this, you'll need to use `std::move` again:

```
void push_back2(
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>& l, std::unique_ptr<int> a)
{
  l.push_back(std::move(a)); // Fine, moves a
  l.push_back(std::move(a)); // Well that was dumb, but you asked for it!
}
```

I hope that I interpreted your question correctly and that this is what you're looking for... let me know if there's anything else I can try to clarify!

Comment: Good point, I had not thought of sending the parameter via `move`. Thx.

Comment: Also, using r-value reference as parameter can help to make sure the function user know that the unique_ptr will loose it's resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide it by rvalue- for example, by function return.

```
unique_ptr<int> make_unique() {
    return unique_ptr<int>(new int);
}
int main() {
    list<unique_ptr<int>> lst;
    lst.push_back(make_unique());
}
```

In addition, you can explicitly `std::move` into the list.